# SharePoint Survey Type Question

Tags: sharepoint-online, survey, survey-list

I have a survey that I'm trying to put into a SP survey.  However, it doesn't fit any of the default survey types.  The survey I'm working with has four (4) columns of words, and about 20 rows across (with four words in each row).  Each row has adjectives that are opposites of each other, and the person taking the survey is supposed to rate each one in each row from "1" to "4", with 1 being strongly agree and 4 being strongly disagree (and the other two in between).

From here, the horizontal columns' numbers should add up, giving the evaluator the final numbers.

I'm a bit stumped.  Any advice?

Comment: Can you update your question with a sample of the data, or a picture of what the results should look like? Not sure what "20 rows across" means.

Comment: I'll see if I can come up with a visual.

Comment: If it helps, it's along the lines of a DISC behaviour summary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SharePoint survey, there is no calculated column to calculate the values of the columns.

I suggest you could use the custom list to achieve it.

You can create the choice columns with radio buttons. And create calculated column to calculate the sum of the choice columns.

The calculated formula as below:

=[choice1]+[choice2]+[choice3]

More reference:

[Calculated Field Formulas.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb862071(v=office.14).aspx)

Comment: I see where you're going here.  This is a possibility.  Thanks, Amy.

Comment: This was what I ended up using.  Didn't want you to think I'd forgotten you ;)